# Запрос согласия от европейских пользователей AdMob

Tags: android, google-play, admob

Здравствуйте я начинающий разработчик, есть приложение на play market, монетизированное с помощью AdMob. Приложение не собирает никаких данных пользователей. С 25 мая вступает в силу Генеральный регламент о защите персональных данных (GDPR). Нужно ли мне получать согласие пользователей из ЕС если в приложении показываеться только реклама от AdMob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше приложение собирает данные и да, прямое согласие юзеров нужно. Даже если вы действительно не собирали бы данные и не показывали бы персонализированную рекламу (а это поведение `AdMob` по умолчанию), то согласие всё одно нужно.

> Ads served by Google can be categorized as personalized or
>   non-personalized, both requiring consent from users in the EEA. By
>   default, ad requests to Google serve personalized ads, with ad
>   selection based on the user's previously collected data. Google also
>   supports configuring ad requests to serve non-personalized ads.

Приложение собирает данные, т.к. гугловая реклама (SDK AdMob) имеет доступ к другим гугловым сервисам, которые собирают инофрмацию и, в т.ч. в `AdID` - собственно идентификатор юзера в гугле для показа персонализированной рекламы.

У гугла есть решение на этот случай. Они запили библиотеку [Google Mobile Ads Consent SDK](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-consent-sdk-android) для запроса у юзера разрешений на доступ к его данным и показа ему персонализированной рекламы. Вот дока: [тык](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent)

И да, если вы не сделаете это, то гугл может удалить ваше приложение/аккаунт и забанить вас за нарушение. А EC может выкатить вам штраф в виде многозначного числа в евро.

А т.к. закон этот действует как на территорию ЕС, так и на её граждан, то бесполезно пытаться определить страну из которой юзер, для решения показывать ему предложение согласиться или нет.