# Нужно ли согласие пользователя на обработку данных в приложении?

Tags: android, юридические-аспекты, персональные-данные

Храню на сервере бесплатного мобильного приложения (с рекламой) пользовательские данные - логин, пароль, геолокация. Нужно ли при регистрации выводить согласие на обработку персональных данных ? Нужно ли в этом согласии указывать одну из сторон (меня) как ИП ? Есть ли у кого шаблоны такого согласия ?
Существует необходимость хранить ответ на согласие ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да нет, в приложении это не надо показывать. Если вы боитесь нового закона GDPR, то, в принципе, достаточно добавить в Google Play ссылку на соглашение (оно на странице в магазине будет показываться).

Можно [этим](https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/) генератором воспользоваться для создания базовой версии.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно

Comment: @VadimPopov да не за что. Сами этим вопросом занимаемся с недавних пор )

Comment: А если своего нету сервера, как добавить ссылку?

Comment: @Романыч лучше у их сапорта спросить. Возможно можно на тот же гитхаб залить.

Comment: А вот в документации к AdMob написано, что согласие надо, если их SDK используется: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/833597/17609

Comment: @ЮрийСПб когда пользователь качает приложение, он принимает соглашение.

Comment: @Suvitruf, я был свидетелем удаления гуглом приложений, которые собирали личные данные (IMEI в этом конкретном случае, но и другие данные сюда попадают). И техподдержка требовала показа непропускаемого экрана с возможностью согласия на это для восстановления приложения или удаления сбора данных. AdMob же собирает данные (и много) по умолчанию. И даже если ему прямо сказать, чтобы он не собирал надо всё равно у юзера спросить. Так у них в документации сказано.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб занятно. Что-то совсем зверство какое-то.

Comment: @Suvitruf, таки да) На работе из-за этого немного паники было) Выяснилось, что дело в либе `AppsFlayer` древней версии, которая этот IMEI` и собирала.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я пока ни в одной игре такого окна не видел. Странно.

Comment: @Suvitruf, скорее всего по тому, что не все озаботились ещё) В моём личном приложении я такой экран встроил более полугода назад вообще. На работе - в последнем обновлении. Правда там его только при регистрации показываем, а не при первом вообще входе в приложение.